# GUI frontend for cURL for testing an API

Tags: api, rest, http, testing, curl

I'm (manually) testing a RESTful API that makes full use of GET/POST/PUT/DELETE methods. Rather than using cURL on the command line to quickly test different input options, it would be handy if there were a windows GUI application to make this easier. Does anything like that exist?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2691) with [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/).

Comment: Note: Poster seems to have been superseded by [HttpRequester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httprequester/). Also, note that both tools will follow redirects when processing the response — this bit me when I wanted to test an API that returned 300 responses.

Comment: @vladr would you please tell me how will  i set post data in poster please ?

Comment: I wrote a REST client plugin called Requester for Sublime Text, https://github.com/kylebebak/Requester. It's inspired by HTTPie and Postman. It's very powerful and easy to use, and it's cross-platform. If you're not in love with your HTTP client it's definitely worth a try.

Comment: HttpRequester link is ded

Comment: There are also ui like https://www.webutils.app/curl-web-ui which generate curl commands

Answer (score 29):

I know this post is a bit old, but [Dev HTTP Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) for Chrome is by far the best plugin I've found.

Along with providing a nice UI that pretty formats responses (like JSON and XML), it allows you to save any requests. IMHO, the best feature is the ability to set different "contexts" and set variables. For instance, you can have a "production" and "dev" context, each with a "host" variable. Then your request string could be `http://${host}/foo`.

Comment: it contains google analytics and asks for signups. dont feel safe

Answer (score 28):

[Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) is a beautiful desktop application for Windows, Mac and Linux for debugging restful APIs (my personal favourite)

[Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) is a Chrome extension for API testing and doing custom http requests. You can save requests for later use, setup different environments (staging, deployment) and collaborate and share requests with others on your team.

[HttpRequester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httprequester/) for Firefox is similar to Postman.

Comment: Insomnia is really something that should get more attention. Having a real desktop application where each call can be saved, categorized and documented is a game changer.

Comment: checkout https://github.com/hoppscotch/hoppscotch

Answer (score 8):

I like [RESTclient](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/).  It doesn't format HTML, though (I assume Poster does), so if you get a 500 error you get to dredge through the return text yourself.

Comment: Looks cool but it runs on Java :-(

Answer (score 8):

Found a useful (free) web tool for this that now exists!

https://curlbuilder.com/

Comment: this is first answer to OP's question. postman and others are separate tools not a gui/wrapper for curl

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Also [XHR POSTER](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/akdbimilobjkfhgamdhneckaifceicen) with [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)
I would say has a better UI then Poster.

**Update**
XHR has been giving me problems. [DHC by Restlet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?utm_source=plus) for Chrome is pretty nice also.

Answer (score 4):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) is a very good tool. You can see history of requests, supports all HTTP verbs, completes the request with necessary headers (like Content-Length). The feature you are looking for is called "Request Builder".

Comment: In current version (Fiddler4) this feature is called 'Composer'

Answer (score 3):

In the interest of trying to keep this list up to date, here is an even better, newer Chrome extension: [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

Answer (score 3):

Try gURL: http://code.google.com/p/gurl/
This is a simple HTTP-request generator, based on curl

Answer (score 3):

Out of all the **Firefox** extensions I tried, [HttpRequester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httprequester/) is the best tool for me. It is very clear and doesn't lack a feature.

For **Chrome**, I would recommend [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) or [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop).

Answer (score 2):

[Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw) for OS X is pretty nice. $29.99 as of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Hurl](http://www.hurl.it) is a great candidate for that?