# Need cURL on Windows PC- Only found 2 versions that are not possible

Tags: windows, http, curl, httpwebrequest

I need a Windows XP/Windows 7 version of cURL. I only have been able to find 2 versions which one has 1) not for windows XP or above and the other I found 2) Must use Microsoft Visual Studio to install it(not possible on the PC I am left to use). Is there any other way to get cURL on the Windows PC I have?

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html ?

Comment: No, that cURL DOS Port is for non Windows XP DOS.

Comment: The link above points to versions that runs on Windows. You need to run it from the cmd prompt. That's how the tool works. Are you specifically asking if a UI exists? If so, please clarify your question.

Comment: Also, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603170/gui-frontend-for-curl-for-testing-an-api