# Json view is not getting by postman

Tags: json, laravel, postman

I have this in my laravel ctrl "Posts" :

```
public function index() {
    $posts = Post::get();
    if (Request::isJson()) {
        return $posts;
    }
    return View::make('posts.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

When i got it via a browser, it's the human view, but with postman (http://www.getpostman.com/) it's the human view too ! So, when i put only the json view, i have it. It's not the normal behavior of postman to get the human view, isn'it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default postman will include an

```
Accept: */*
```

header.

If you specifically want json you should send an

```
Accept: application/json
```

header.

Comment: How can we **remove** the header?

Comment: @Pacerier Postman automatically applies `Accept: */*` only if you didn't provide an explicit header.  AFAIK you cannot send a request with no Accept header at all via postman.

Comment: Dang, what's a better program that allows us to do more customizations?

Comment: @Pacerier curl can do almost anything.  Fiddler is very useful for capturing and modifying requests.

Comment: But there isn't a GUI program for curl is there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603170/gui-frontend-for-curl-for-testing-an-api